# Retrieve all occurrences of a partial string

Tags: php, regex

In my string (which is effectively the HTML for a single page) I have a number of tags I want to access and replace with the relevant content.

eg:

```
<p>[@intro_text]</p>
```

Will become:

```
<p>introduction text!</p>
```

This is all simple enough to do with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) but I also have a series of tags like the following:

```
[@snippet_searchbox]
[@snippet_contactbox]
```

I need to find all occurrences of these tags **[@snippet_?????]** in the html.

I essentially just want to end up with an array of all tag names.  From this I can easily find the content that it should be replaced with.

eg:

```
Array
(
    [0] => snippet_searchbox
    [1] => snippet_contactbox
    [2] => snippet_somethingelse
)
```

What is the best way to do this?  I have been playing around with **[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)** but I get cross-eyed whenever I attempt regex, even though I am certain this is pretty simple.

Any suggestions would be grateful, and if it should be done with regex if someone could help me with the regex code I should user.  Thanks!

Comment: How are you mapping your text to your snippets?

Comment: [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is the best for your situation (if I correctly got it)..

Comment: Is your html very clean, which mean without strange line breaks ?

Comment: I have looked at preg_replace_callback() but I still need to know the regex to use.  Essentially I just want to end up with an array of all the snippets on my page, eg [0] -> snippet_searchbox, [1] -> snippet_contactbox.

Comment: You did not [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) in more than a week. Can you please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11050279/edit) to point out why none of the answers solve your question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I did update my question (see my response to @Panique below). I am looking for the regex to work with _preg_replace_callback_ or _preg_match_all_ so I find all occurrences of the tag **[@snippet_?????]**.  I would ideally like the full tags to end up in an array that I can loop through.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inventing your own syntax for these identifiers, use regular (X)HTML attributes:

```
<html>
    …
    <p id="intro_text"></p>
    …    
    <div id="searchbox"></div>
    …
    <div id="contactbox"></div>
    …
</html>
```

or namespaced elements:

```
<html>
    …
    <p tpl:id="intro_text"></p>
    …    
    <tpl:snippet id="searchbox"/>
    …
    <tpl:snippet id="contactbox"/>
    …
</html>
```

Then use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) and [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html) to find and replace/modify them. There is plenty of examples on StackOverflow on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace()`:

```
$tags = array(
 '[@intro_text]'        => 'introduction text!',
 '[@snippet_searchbox]' => '<div>some text</div>',
 /* more items here */
);

$html = str_replace(array_keys($tags), array_values($tags), $html);
```

Comment: wow, didn't know the simple fact that str_replace can handle ARRAYs ;)

Comment: I can't use str_replace as I can't manually reference the snippets.  I need to retrieve the full name of the snippet tag so I can then find the relevant content to replace it with.  This needs to be quite dynamic, it's worth assuming my code doesn't know the name of the snippets, just that they will start with [@snippet_

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply using str_replace ?

```
str_replace("[@intro_text]", $new_content_of_intro_text, $html_file);
```

Comment: I have updated my post to hopefully make this clearer.  I can't use str_replace as this needs to be dynamic.  My code won't know what snippets are on the page, just that they will all start with [@snippet_